# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, module

[tensorflow module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50ODj.png)

[version of keras and tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIdHP.png)

I just want to know why it doesn't work., Because I read through the threads but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Run：

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0 --user
pip uninstall tensorflow-datasets
pip install tensorflow-datasets==4.0.0
```

And reconnect google colab.